# imported Unity fbx model animation is distorted?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, maya

Alright, Ive posted to unity forums too but I usually turn to stack overflow and need to see if anyone else has experienced this problem -

I am working in C# in Unity and we have been importing a maya fbx model with the animations BAKED in on export into the project. We have used the same model for all the animations and just importing separate animated models in because I need to (via animation controller) apply different animations to the same model. Not switch different models in and out.

This was working with different versions of one animation (the idle), but all of a sudden a version of a different animation (on the SAME MODEL, same export settings) when I drag and drop the animation file to the existing model in Unity, the model is distorted playing the animation.

This is what happens - everything actually plays as it did before with other working animations, except the torso is displaced

[image]

We;ve checked and none of the keyframes in Maya changed between the 2 models regarding the torso. My question is - has anyone experienced this? Is there a certain setting/box in unity that is preventing 2 animations on the same model from playing without distortion?

What causes distortion of imported animated models?

Comment: Does the distortion occur when playing the animation or simply when the model is imported?

Comment: When I take the animation from imported model and attach it to the controller of the model already in the game, and I play the animation this happens

Comment: Very likely you are animating the color in the controller. I can't tell because the scene is not in front of me but I do believe that the color is being  modified or perhaps, a bad uv unwrapping....

Comment: The color? what do you mean - the model itself is distorted - see his body is where his head is. How does that have to do with color?